# How to increase camera capture quality in Win8 metro app VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, camera, windows-8.1

I'm developing an app for windows 8 which takes photos from webCamera, the current quality (either .jpg or .png) is

- height and width: 640X480
- resolution:       96ppp
- deep in bits:     24Bits

---

```
function takePhoto() {
    //if a file with the same name exist, creates another with a number at the end
    pics.createFileAsync("photo.jpg", Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName)
      .then(function (file) {   
          var photoProperties = Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.createJpeg();
          var photoProperties = Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.createPng();

          mediaCapture.capturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(photoProperties, file).then(function () {
              console.log("Image saved on disk. ");

              var thumbnailUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });

              previewSlide(thumbnailUrl);
          });
      });
}
```

if I compare current screenshots with native camera's screenshots the quality of native camera's app is superior, I want to get the same result as native camera, or if not possible, I want to increase picture quality, how to achieve that?

thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:** pictures trying to resolve **MediaStreamType**

[image]

[image]

---

Function for initializing camera:

```
function startCamera() {
        mediaCapture = new Capture.MediaCapture();

        mediaCapture.initializeAsync().then(function () {

            var iVectorView = mediaCapture.videoDeviceController.getAvailableMediaStreamProperties(Windows.Media.Capture.MediaStreamType.photo);

            for (var i = 0; i < iVectorView.length; i++) {
                console.log("elemento " + i + ":" + iVectorView[i]);
            }



            mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(iVectorView[], properties);
            mediaCapture.videoDeviceController.setm


            livePreview.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaCapture);
            livePreview.play();
        });

        livePreview.addEventListener("pause", handlePause);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my stop motion animation app, [Zoetrope](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/zoetrope/0fab6b06-702a-4f22-95c3-a8c1e804c0a0):

1. Call `mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(Windows.Media.Capture.MediaStreamType.Photo)` to get all of the available photo profiles and cast the results to `VideoEncodingProperties`
2. Each of the stream properties returned will have attributes like width, height, and color depth - select one that is appropriate for your use case.
3. Call `mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, properties) with the VideoEncodingProperties that you want to use.`

Comment: I added the first line but it says MediaStreamType is not defined, what kind of variable or object is MediaStreamType?

Comment: Jesus, in Visual Studio, right click on MediaStreamType and select Resolve...using Window.Media.Capture and the correct using statement will be added to your file.

Comment: I looked for "Resolve" option but didn't found that option what do I need to do, pictures in my question, I just replaced the "MediaStreamType.Photo" for "Windows.Media.Capture.MediaStreamType.Photo" going to put the function where I initialize my camera as well

Comment: I thought you were working in C# - in JS you need to use the whole type name or define it beforehand as a var like this: var MediaStreamType=Windows.Media.Capture.MediaStreamType;